# Structs and External binary files to store data

Tags: c++

Alright so I have an [assignment](http://pastebin.com/qx1haD9x) that I have been completely stumped on. My code thus far is as follows

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 12;

struct Division
{
      char divName[SIZE]; // Division name
      double sales[4]; // Quarterly sales stored as an array
};



int main()
{
       void Intro();
       Division CreateCorporateFile();
       Division DisplayCorporateSales();

       Intro();
       CreateCorporateFile();
       DisplayCorporateSales();


       system("PAUSE");
       return 0;
}

void Intro()
{
     cout<<"This program will prompt you to enter in quarterly sales for "
           "four different\ndivisions of a company.\n\n";
}


Division CreateCorporateFile()
{
     Division div;
     int x = 0;
     //for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
 do {
          int quarter = 1;
          cout << "Enter the name of the division: ";
          cin >> div.divName;
          for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
          {
              cout << "Enter in the sales for quarter "<< quarter <<": ";
               cin >> div.sales[i];
               if(div.sales[i] > 0)
               {
                    quarter++;
               }
               else
               {
                    cout << "Sales are not allowed to be negative.\n";
               }
          }
          x++;
     } while(x < 4);

     return div;
}


Division DisplayCorporateSales()
{
         Division test;

         Division CreateCorporateFile();

         test = CreateCorporateFile();

         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         {
             cout << "Here are the quarterly sales for " << test.divName
              << ": ";
             for(int i = 0, quarter = 1; i < 4; ++i, ++quarter)
             {
                  cout << "Quarter "<< quarter << " sales: $"<< test.sales[i]
                   <<"\n";
             }
         }

         return test;

}
```

One of the problems that I am running in to is that it ends up prompting for 8 divisions (should only do it 4 times), and another is that it ends up only displaying the 8th divisions data. So anybody see where I am going wrong? Because I do not, and I have been working on it for hours so I am probably overlooking obvious details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you only display data for the final `Division` is that `CreateCorporateFile` only returns a single `Division` instance.  Each do-while loop overwrites the contents of the previous loop.

One solution to this would be to return an array instead

```
std::vector<Division> CreateCorporateFile()
{
    std::vector<Division> divArray;
    Division div;
    int x = 0;
    do {
        ...
        divArray.push_back(div);
        x++;
    } while(x < 4);

    return divArray;
}

void DisplayCorporateSales()
{
    std::vector<Division> divisions = CreateCorporateFile();
    for (size_t i=0; i<divisions.size(); i++)
    {
        Division div = divisions[i];
        cout << "Here are the quarterly sales for " << div.divName
        << ": ";
        for(int j = 0, quarter = 1; j < 4; ++j, ++quarter)
        {
            cout << "Quarter "<< quarter << " sales: $"<< div.sales[j]
            <<"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So would I do [this](http://pastebin.com/kgQixhGt)? This doesn't seem right. (I am not very proficient in C++)

Comment: @Kobrien Can you rephrase your question please?  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to word it the best I can. I need to collect data, from the user, on four divisions of a company and their quarterly sales (in the form of a struct). I then need to write this struct to a binary file and also display the results to the screen. At least that is what I think my [assignment](http://pastebin.com/qx1haD9x) is trying to get me to do.

Comment: @Kobrien That's correct.  Your DisplayCorporateSales method will then need to iterate through each element of the vector.  I'll update my answer to give you an idea how that's done.

Comment: Okay, so what would I return from DisplayCorporateSales()? I would return div, correct?

Comment: Oops, now corrected to return void in my answer.  I wouldn't expect a function named Display to return anything.  If you find you need a return from it, I imagine returning the same vector would be more useful.

Comment: That does make sense (returning the same vector if I were going to return something). With this I am getting an error that "'vector' is not a member of 'std'". It is pointing to the first two lines in CreatCorporateFile().

Comment: You'll need to add `#include <vector>`

Comment: Hmm thought I had that already, guess not. Not trying to be a bother but now there is this error, "conversion from `std::vector<Division, std::allocator<Division> >' to non-scalar type `Division' requested "

Comment: The error is pointing to return divArray; in CreatCorporateFile().

Comment: Did you remember to change the return type for that function?  In both the implementation and any forward declaration?

Comment: Whoops, I missed it in one spot. Guess I need to look more closely next time. Alright, I thought that would fix everything, but there is, yet another, error. It says, "insufficient contextual information to determine type" and it is pointing to cout << "Here are the quar...." in Display.

Comment: That's surprising.  That line should be effectively identical to your original code.  Are you passing `div.divName` here?

Comment: I did [this](http://pastebin.com/1nSJptNN) it now compiles and runs but it does not have any data in divName. I am running into the problem where it prompts for 8 divisions again though. [Here](http://pastebin.com/k10EgrEa) is my complete code as of this moment.

Comment: I can't see any reason for that.  It might be worth marking this question as resolved then posting a new question with your updated source, asking about the prompts for 8 divisions.  It'd be good to also include a copy of your prompts/responses in the new question.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is caused by you declaring the functions you are going to use inside main rather than before it in global scope:
       void Intro();
       Division CreateCorporateFile();
       Division DisplayCorporateSales();

The second problem is caused by the fact that you have used the variable `i` twice for each of your loops. You need to use a different variable name (or just use `quarter` as a loop variable).